# How to store session cookie properly with proper lifetime?

Tags: php, session, symfony, session-cookies, session-timeout

Let's say I want to keep session for users for 12 hours. I set:

```
cookie_lifetime = 43200
gc_maxlifetime = 43200
```

above times are in seconds. My session memory limit is set to 400MB. Website has about 10k users. After some days it turned out that there is no disk space. How to properly set session to not expire it before 12 hours but delete it after it will expire, so it won't make disk full ?

I know there is php cron job that clears unused sessions after 30 minutes. Shouldn't this be cleared automatically ? also Garbage Collection should deal with it after set maxlifetime is set. Or simply increasing memory limit to ~1024MB should do the trick ? if so is it a proper way to handle this ? I hope someone will make it clear for me.

Comment: This has been documented a little bit here http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/session_configuration.html#session-idle-time-keep-alive but it doesn't really explain any real solution, I also think that it has been added as a feature request aswel

Comment: @takeit , maybe it not what you asked for, but why don't you wanna to use memcache to store sessions ? In this case you solve two issues with one shot. Memcache sessions works faster then file, and old sessions will be deleted automatically due to memecache mechanism. There is native methods to switch sessions to memecache in symfony.

Comment: okay guys, I will check Memcache. Thanks for now!